# Running code after creating object with Grace IoC

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, grace-ioc

I'd like to call a method on an object after it's been created and all of the dependencies have been loaded, but before it's returned to the caller of `Locate()` . How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in 6.3.0 you have the ability to apply cross cutting functionality using the ExportInitialize extension

`container.Configure(
     c => c.ExportInitialize<ISomeInterface>(instance => instance.SomeMethod()));`